# history.listen not triggered in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react-router v4 for routing, to parse query params, it has been recommended to use `history.listen` [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410)

I am calling it within the lifecycle hook `componentDidMount` to ensure that the component has mounted so that I can provide it as a piece of component state using a Higher Order Component like this:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import qs from 'qs';
import { compose, lifecycle, withState } from 'recompose';

export const history = createHistory();
const withQs = compose(
  withState('search', 'setSearch', {}),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount: function () {
      // works on the client side
      history.listen(() => {
        // history.location = Object.assign(history.location,
          // parse the search string using your package of choice
        // { query: parseQueryString(history.location.search) }
        // )
        console.log('History Location', history.location);
        console.log('Search', history.location.search);
      })
    }
  })
)

export default withQs
```

The `history.listen` is never triggered when a route navigates to the new page or a new query param is added to the page.

Comment: Are you using that same exported `history` instance throughout your project? i.e. are you using it to render `<Router history={history}>`?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of your code showing where you  use the React Router V4 components?

Comment: I am also having issues with `listen()` not firing. I have the history assigned to my Router's history like this: `<Router history={history}>` and I expect `listen()` to fire when the route changes but it never does.

Comment: @PaulS yes, however I have to mention that I am using `import BrowserRouter as Router from react-router-dom`.

Comment: @ToddChaffee I can link you to a github repo [here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/learn-rr4), the [hoc is here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/learn-rr4/blob/8084f56522816cea216ce5231dc3e5ac5c2491f5/src/containers/queryParams.js) I have since replaced it with `global` as a temporary workaround I am not happy with. I have removed recompose to make it simpler but older commits will show the version that uses recompose.

Comment: You need to use `<Router>`, not `<BrowserRouter>`. `<BrowserRouter>` creates its own `history` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [React Router V4 docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router), if you want to manage history yourself, you need to use `<Router>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>`:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```